# How to get the outer class of an inner class which also inside inner class

Tags: java, nested

How can i get the outer instance?

```
class OuterClass {

    class InnerClass {
        class MoreInnerClass {
            public MoreInnerClass() {
            // i want to get outer class from here
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to get The OuterClass instance from the MoreInnerClass methods.

Comment: I believe you can use the qualified "this"..`OuterClass.this`

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
OuterClass.this.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {
        class MoreInnerClass {
            public MoreInnerClass() {
                OuterClass.this.hashCode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the classes is static this should do:

```
OuterClass.this
```